# mxmlDelete () usage

Tags: c, xml, mini-xml

I use [mxml](http://www.minixml.org/index.php) library to parse XML file in C language. I load my XML in buffer using the following code:

```
mxml_node_t *tree; 
tree = mxmlLoadString(NULL,XMLbuf,MXML_OPAQUE_CALLBACK);
```

The XML file is complicated but this is irrelevant at the moment.

My question is : when I should free memory used by the mxml library functions?

Is it enough to use code like this once and for all:

```
mxmlDelete(tree);
```

or I have to repeat that for every node of my `XML.(mxmlDelete(node1);mxmlDelete(node2);` until I reach `mxmlDelete(tree);`?

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](http://www.minixml.org/documentation.php/reference.html#mxmlDelete) clearly states the answer:

> Delete a node and all of its children.

So if you call this on a top-level node (the tree's root), you should be done.

Comment: Yes ,node and all of its children but what about "next" node? I am not sure if one call of mxmlDalete(tree) free all "children" and "next" nodes or only tree's "children" nodes